# sed not liking regex syntax

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I am trying to run the following command on a file to get the first 3 parts of the version number:

```
sed -nE 's/^([\d.]+)(?=\.)/\1/' version
```

The file is as follows:

```
1.2.3.4
```

I am expecting `1.2.3` to output as per the regex I tested on regexr but for some reason there is an inconsistency between regexr's syntax and what sed expects and I keep on getting the following errors:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 21: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Comment: You are using Perl-style regular expressions, which `sed` doesn't not recognize.

Comment: `sed -E 's/(.*)\..*/\1/' version` should suffice.

Comment: Even with the nonstandard `-E` extension (or its `-r` equivalent on GNU systems), sed supports ERE, not PCRE. (Without it, the syntax supported is BRE).

Comment: ...btw, why are you bothering with `sed` for this at all? `content=$(<version); echo "${content%.*}"` will do what you want, using only capabilities built into bash.

Comment: BTW, questions about `sed` are *not* in and of themselves questions about bash! `sed` doesn't come with bash, and the version of `sed` you have and the version of `bash` you have are completely unrelated. Bash's built-in regular expression support (as used in the `[[ $string =~ $regex ]]` operator) is ERE, as composed to `sed`'s specification only guaranteeing BRE support.

Comment: Also, consider reading [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) and [the bash-hackers page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) to get a handle on string-manipulation support built into bash before reaching for `sed` or similar external tools. Those external tools will typically perform better when processing large amounts of data -- but for just one line, the cost to start them up overwhelms any savings.

Comment: (argh, "as compared with". Brain/finger mismatch there).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only functionality `sed` is guaranteed to provide is that given in [its POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/sed.html). This refers in turn to [the POSIX Basic Regular Expressions syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03), with a very limited set of guaranteed extensions. By contrast, both `(?=...)` and `\d` are [PCRE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) extensions, not even available in [POSIX ERE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_04).

---

`sed` supports BRE (by default), or ERE (with platform-specific extensions such as `-r` or `-E`). `\d` is not part of either of these; neither is `(?=...)`.

An ERE equivalent would be:

```
sed -Ee 's/^([[:digit:].]+)[.][^.]*$/\1/' version
```

...or a BRE equivalent (working with baseline POSIX sed):

```
sed -e 's/[.][[:digit:]]\{1,\}$//' version
```

...or, even better, not using `sed` at all but sticking to bash built-in capabilities:

```
full_version=$(<version)   # or full_version=$(cat version) on non-bash shells
version=${full_version%.*} # trim everything after the last "."
```

Comment: And how would I extract the last part after the last period, but not including the period?

Comment: `last_piece=${full_version##*.}`; see [the bash-hackers page on parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe), and [BashFAQ #100](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) (on string manipulation in general).

Answer (score 0):

To complement [Charles Duffy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40987017/45375):

If the only content of your `version` file is a version number, the following `bash` commands are an alternative if you want a *fixed* number of components:

```
 IFS='.' read -r maj min rev _ < version
 ver=$maj.$min.$rev  # with the sample input, $ver is now '1.2.3'
```

This extracts only the first 3 `.`-separated tokens from the (first line of the) input (the remainder of the line, if any, is assigned to unused var. `$_`), and then rebuilds them into a 3-component version number.

---

A `perl` alternative (which is a bit heavy-handed for a single version number; lines that don't match are passed through as-is):

```
perl -pe 's/^((\d+\.){3}).*/$1/; s/\.$//' version
```